# Matlab SimPowerSystem simple generator implementation

Tags: matlab

I want to implement the simple following configuration with Simulink,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/39lhT.jpg

For the generator I used 
**Synchronous Machine SI Fundamental**
from the SimPowerSystem Toolbox.
For the load I used 
**Three-Phase Series RLC Branch**
from the SimPowerSystem Toolbox.

If the inductance is zero, the simulation runs.
But if the inductance is non zero, I got the error message :

> Error using powersys
>   at 16
>   The following two blocks
>   cannot be connected in series:
>
> Block 1: 'A: Synchronous Machine SI
>   Fundamental'
>
> Block 2: 'phase_A:
>   Three-Phase Series RLC Branch'

I checked in the SimPowerSystem documentation, there is no reference about this problem. Is it an error of implementation ?

Answer (score 1):

Trying with other load blocks, I got the following message :

> The first block, modeled as a current
>   source cannot be connected in series
>   with the inductive element of the
>   second block.

I had a high value resistance in parallel with the Three-Phase Series RLC branch, it solved the problem.